# Как определять одиночные нажатия в консоли?

Tags: c#

Привет! Я новичок в C# и меня интересует вопрос:как сделать, чтоб консоль распознавала только одиночные нажатия клавиш и игнорировала их зажатие? (И возможно ли это сделать вообще в консольном C#?
UPD: Добавил код для понимания. Задача состоит в том, чтобы консоль выводила число только после одиночного нажатия клавиши, а при ее зажатии не выводила ничего.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press \u0022Enter\u0022 to play!");
        int num = 0;
        void WaitForKey(ConsoleKey key)
        {
            while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != key)
            {

            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            WaitForKey(ConsoleKey.Enter);
            Console.Write("{0}", num);
            num++;
        }                                                                   
    }
```

UPD.2: новая версия кода, теперь проблема в том, что между нажатиями одной клавиши надо нажимать другую.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press \u0022Enter\u0022 to play!");
        int num = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            do
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo keypress;
                ConsoleKeyInfo oldkeypress;

                keypress = Console.ReadKey(true);
                oldkeypress = keypress;

                keypress = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if (oldkeypress != keypress)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", num);
                    num++; ;
                    oldkeypress = keypress;
                }

            } while (1==1);
        }
```

Comment: Немного непонятен вопрос. Ты хочешь что бы когда в консоле ты нажимаешь клавишу допустим "А" то не чего не произойдёт? А если "AS" то должно реагировать?

Comment: Если нужно считать один символ, то `Console.ReadKey()` в этом поможет, зажатия клавиш будут игнорироваться. А если надо всё таки вести слово/строку, то тут только самому писать проверки.

Comment: @Павел я хочу, чтоб когда я нажимаю (условно говоря) А, то мне б выводило А только 1 раз вместо АААААААААА.

Comment: Думаю, без использования WinAPI тут нет решения

Comment: @Андрей да и с WinAPI не сильно проще, но возможно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша задача сложнее чем кажется. Проблемы:

1. Обычные консольные программы не слушают события ввода системы и, как следствие, не могут их обрабатывать без дополнительных извращений.
2. Методы чтения класса `System.Console` только читают входной поток (не обязательно стандартный), но не управляют им, поэтому вы не можете отличить многократное нажатие на клавишу с отпусканием от простого "зажатия" или "залипания" клавиши, т.к. система регистрирует все нажатия и складывает во входной поток.
3. Из предыдущих пунктов следует, что даже с привлечением WinAPI через PInvoke, без работы и, в некотором смысле, костылей не обойтись.

Не испугало? Тогда поехали.

Я намерено оставляю за кадром варианты с подключением диспетчера сообщений, скрытыми окнами и прочие не слишком честные, по отношению к консоли, методы. Желающие могут написать это отдельным ответом. Тут только хардкор, только честная и чистая консоль + немного WinAPI(PInvoke)! =)

Нам понадобится импортировать две функции WinAPI: `getkeystate`([WinAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646301(v=vs.85).aspx), [PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getkeystate)) и `getkeyboardstate` ([WinAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646299(v=vs.85).aspx), [PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getkeyboardstate)). Сделаем это в отдельном классе.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

static class ConsoleNative
{
    //получение состояния всех клавиш, включая служебные и мышь
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GetKeyboardState(byte [] lpKeyState);

    //сюда будем писать состояния клавиш
    private static byte[] keys = new byte[256];  

    //получение состояния указанной клавиши
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern short GetKeyState(int key);
```

Импорт необходимого завершен, делаем проверку на "нажатость". Для примера будем обрабатывать все виртуальные клавиши, включая мышь, вы можете легко изменить это поведение добавив исключение ненужных клавиш (список клавиш [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx))

```
    public static bool IsAnyKeyPressed()
    {
        //По совету с PInvoke, добавлено для того, чтобы нормально отрабатывала 
        //GetKeyboardState
        GetKeyState(0);

        if(!GetKeyboardState(keys))
        {
            //защита на всякий случай, у меня ни разу не сработала, но...
            int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            throw new Win32Exception(err);
        }
        //каждый байт - это состояние одной из клавиш
        for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        {
            if(i < 7)
            {
                //байты с 0 по 6 отвечают за клавиши мыши, проигнорируем их
                keys[i] = 0;
            }
            else
            {    
                //за состояние "нажатости" отвечает старший бит, остальное просто зануляем
                keys[i] = (byte)(keys[i] & 0x80);
            }
        }
        return keys.Any(k => k != 0);
    }
```

Добавим пару хелперов для красоты и удобства при использовании

```
    public static void WaitForKeyDown()
    {
        bool isAnyKeyPressed;
        do
        {
            isAnyKeyPressed = IsAnyKeyPressed();
        }
        while(!isAnyKeyPressed);
    }

    public static void WaitForKeyUp()
    {
        bool isAnyKeyPressed;
        do
        {
            isAnyKeyPressed = IsAnyKeyPressed();
        }
        while(isAnyKeyPressed);
    }

    //очистка входного потока от нажатых клавиш. Мы же не хотим 
    //при следующем вызове Console.ReadXXX прочитать все, что нажимали до этого?
    public static void FlushInputStream()
    {
        while(Console.KeyAvailable)
            Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Все, класс для работы с клавиатурой завершен, но вы можете добавить туда что-то свое, если будет необходимость.

Теперь как этим монстром пользоваться? Смотрим, это относительно легко, хотя свои условности конечно есть:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    do
    {
        //ждем, пока нажмут клавишу
        ConsoleNative.WaitForKeyDown();
        //ждем пока отпустят клавишу
        ConsoleNative.WaitForKeyUp();
        //с помощью Console.ReadKey читаем что было нажато
        var key = Console.ReadKey(true);
        if(!Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            //если было одиночное нажатие выводим нажатое
            Console.WriteLine(key.KeyChar);
        }
        else
        {
            //если было залипание чистим входной поток от мусора
            ConsoleNative.FlushInputStream();
        }            
    }
    while(true);
}
```

Весь фокус тут в том, что ожидание нажатия и отпускания клавиши сделаны не через чтение входного потока, а прямыми запросами к системе. Это позволяет в последствии читать из потока только то, что нас интересует и сбрасывать лишнее.

В описанном примере есть один недостаток, если клавиши нажимать достаточно быстро, то некоторые клавиши не будут обработаны, красивого решения пока найти не удалось, но поставленная задача в общем уже решается - программа реагирует только на одиночные нажатия.

Отдельные фрагменты можно улучшить или написать более изящно, но это всего лишь демонстрационный пример, как можно решить данную задачу не прибегая к хитрым трюкам со скрытыми окнами и т.д.

Comment: Офигеть. Спасибо за развернутый ответ, обязательно попробую. А там где занулить клавиши, вместо 0х80 написать каждую клавишу из того списка кроме необходимой мне?

Comment: @SergeyYershykhin ну для тех что нужны keys[i] = keys[i] & 0х80, для тех что не нужны keys[i] = 0

Comment: То есть keys[i] = 0 & (номер клавиши)?

Comment: @SergeyYershykhin код клавиши определяется индексом в массиве, поэтому для игнорирования клавиши нужно просто пропустить элемент с индексом, совпадающим с кодом клавиши или вписать в элемент 0

Comment: туплю. Можете пожалуйста на примере любой клавиши показать как ее игнорировать?

Comment: @SergeyYershykhin обновил

Answer (score 0):

Поправил код теперь он по идее должен подойти.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo keypress;
            ConsoleKeyInfo oldkeypress;

            keypress = Console.ReadKey(true);
            oldkeypress = keypress;
            do
            {
                keypress = Console.ReadKey(true); // read keystrokes
                if (oldkeypress != keypress)
                { Console.Write(keypress.KeyChar);
                    oldkeypress = keypress;
                }

            } while (1==1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Перенаправить вывод в никуда, что бы не выводить в консоль вообще ничего и только поставить обработку на ctrl+e и alt+e? Нет, это даже не близко к тому, что спрашивал автор. Он спрашивал про то, что если зажать клавишу и не отпускать ее, то будет постоянный вывод и надо этого избежать.

Comment: @AlexKrass именно!

Comment: @ArchiFox нет, это не то. Alex Krass правильнее описал мою проблему.

Comment: @SergeyYershykhin хорошо сейчас попробую найти решение.

Comment: @SergeyYershykhin поправил код посмотрите.. возможно подойдёт данная реализация.. ели нет то уж извините идей больше нету.

Comment: @ArchiFox почти то что нужно. Единственная проблема - чтоб нажимать одну и ту же кнопку, между нажатиями надо нажать на другую и это не вписывается в концепцию моей проги. Я сейчас изменю код в посте, мб подскажете что исправить?

Comment: @SergeyYershykhin, простите решения пока не нашёл. посмотрю дома может что и получится. Использование функции "Console.KeyAvailable" не дала результатов.Так как почему-то  практически всегда возвращает false..  не знаю возможно это баг у меня на ПК либо сам чего-то не недопонимаю. С#-ом  так же как и вы недавно занялся.